# Find match and if true replace

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So what I would like to be able to do is take a list and if there is a match below a cell I want to use this formula =--REPLACE(A1,1,2,99).

I have this which will mark them true. However I want to use the fromula from above.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"="&A2),"True","")
```

**Example**

```
1111111 AAA = 1111111
2222222 BBB = 2222222
3333333 CCC = 9933333
4444444 CCC = 4444444
5555555 DDD = 5555555
6666666 EEE = 9966666
7777777 EEE = 7777777
8888888 FFF = 8888888
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the COUNTIF() Just use this:

```
=IF(B1=B2,--REPLACE(A1,1,2,99),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Would I be able to add a formula to this incase it was false?Sorry I did not think I was going to need a false formula.

Comment: Yes just replace the A1 with the formula you want.